# Improve performance of shell script used to update HTML files

Tags: bash, shell

I am using the below code to generate HTML files. There are several hundred HTMLs that get updated & each have several thousand URLs in them that gets updated.

I thought the below code would be reasonably fast to execute. However, it's taking over an hour to process the data which is unacceptable. Sometimes it can be over 2 hours.

Please can I get help to improve the performance of this code?

```
update_index_page(){
   echo "Updating $1"
        mega_string=''
        while read line
        do
                subitem=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"#" '{print $3}')
                short_url="<a href=\"https://mywebsite.com/${1}/${subitem}.html\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">${subitem}</a>"
                mega_string="${mega_string}<tr><td>${short_url}</td><td>$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"#" '{print $2}')</td><td>$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"#" '{print $1}')</td></tr>"
        done<"${TMP_LOC}/${1}.txt"
        echo "${HTML_PART_1}${mega_string}${HTML_PART_2}${HTML_PART_3}" > ${CODE_LOC}${1}/index.html
        if [[ "${1}" == "All-Items" ]]
        then
                to_replace=$1"andALL"
                sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDEREXCHANGENAME/$to_replace/g" ${CODE_LOC}${1}/index.html
        else
                sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDEREXCHANGENAME/$1/g" ${CODE_LOC}${1}/index.html
        fi
}


while read line
do
    update_index_page "$line"
done<"$INPUT_FILE"
```

Comment: For every `line` you invoke `awk` 3 times and `sed` once. That requires spawning 4 subshells per `line` you read. That will be slow. It is quite likely you can do the entire thing with a single call to `awk` that will be *orders-of-magnitude* faster than a shell script. What I mean is replace your entire shell script with an `awk` script. `awk` is designed to read "records" (lines) and operate on the lines. There is very little you can't do in `awk`. See [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Comment: You should provide a sample of your HTML page and `INPUT_FILE`. Also, `sed`/`grep`/`awk` aren't the best tools for manipulating XML/HTML but I guess it can be done if you're author of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the section in python which takes about 10 min to complete as against 2 or more hours earlier.